# Azure Storage Not Showing in Visual Studio 2015 Server Explorer

Tags: azure-storage, visual-studio-2015

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 and cloned a repo from my Visual Studio Online account. Originally the code was written with Visual Studio 2013 and with that environment I could see my Azure Storage Account (i.e. Tables, Queues and Blobs) under the Azure connection section on the Server Explorer. However with Visual Studio 2015 I can see the Azure connection section which includes App Service, Mobile Service, Notification Hubs and SQL Database but no Storage.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.  I decided to upgrade to the latest as of now Azure SDK 2.7.  This fixed my server explorer panel and also added in a new panel called Cloud Explorer.  This will hopefully get you going.  Here is the link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/20/announcing-the-azure-sdk-2-7-for-net/

Comment: It was really nice of Microsoft to confuse us and show some Azure stuff in Server Explorer even when the Azure SDK is not installed...and then when you install the right SDK you get Cloud Explorer which is another tool with lack of features and direction.

Comment: At some point, the 'cloud explorer' feature was removed from the massive Azure SDK. It now seems to live as a separate plugin: ['Cloud Explorer for Visual Studio 2015'](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/84e83a7c-9606-4f9f-83dd-0f6182f13add)