# Missing Azure Components in Visual Studio 2015 Server Explorer

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

I've installed VS 2015 Enterprise side-by-side with VS 2013 Update 5. When I open Server Explorer in both versions and expand my Azure-Node there is a difference between the 2 studios.

In the new 2015 one I only can see "App Service", "Mobile Service", "Notification Hubs" and "SQL Databases". All other nodes are missing.

Second problem: When I hit "Manage" the dialog inside the VS 2015 will not show all of my subscriptions. Only 2 of 4 are displayed.

Is this a nown "feature" or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was already asked in
[Azure Storage Not Showing in Visual Studio 2015 Server Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549023/azure-storage-not-showing-in-visual-studio-2015-server-explorer)

I can vouch that the suggested solution (install Azure SDK 2.7 from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=518003&clcid=0x409) worked on my PC.

Comment: Simple as that! I thought, I already installed it but the Visual Studio Update Link simply points to the 2.6. Thanks!